# SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN error angular protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-e2e

I'm running e2e test in angular app using protractor, and I proxy the backend requests to link that run under corporate network and I keep getting `SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN` error; I have tried `webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl`, `npm config set strict-ssl`, and `npm config set ca ""` none of them worked. is there a way to fix this?